# Working with XNA?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna

I'd like to develop a small game but as I created a Windows Phone Game-Solution, all I get is C#.

I am used to have access to Expression Blend, to edit "Pages" and their elements, so that I can implement their codes behind seperated in Visual Studio.

Is there a way, to have something like that (Visual Studio for code/Blend for UI) for XNA games? After all I work with people who don't understand code at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no visual editor for XNA projects. You will have to write the core or use third-party libraries to facilitate the development.

Comment: Could you recommend some 3rd party software, which I could use for basic game development?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the FlatRedBall-Engine, its based off XNA and has some (quite clunky) editors.

I would recommend you the Beefball-Tutorial: http://www.flatredball.com/frb/docs/index.php?title=Tutorials:Beefball

Answer (score 1):

this one I recommend for people who are beginners in XNA and WP7

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2012/03/02/xna-for-windows-phone-walkthrough-creating-the-bizzy-bees-game.aspx